# C# use Linq to pull data from xml

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have problem with building object holding XML data using Linq. For example, I have XML data in url http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&usesystem=30000142 . In `MarketStat` class I want to hold `type id` value and in `MarketValue` class array I want to hold `volume` `avg` `max` `min` `stddev` `median` `percentile`values of `buy` `sell` `all` nodes. I have never used linq so far so please help me fix my problem in code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class MarketValue
    {
        public int Volume { get; set; }
        public double Avg { get; set; }
        public double Max { get; set; }
        public double Min { get; set; }
        public double Stddev { get; set; }
        public double Median { get; set; }
        public double Percentile { get; set; }
    }
    internal class MarketStat
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public MarketValue[] MarketValueses { get; set; }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        private static List<MarketStat> list;
        internal static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            list = (
                from e in XDocument.Load("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&usesystem=30000142").
                    Root.Elements("marketstat")
                select new MarketStat
                {
                    Name = (string) e.Element("type id"),
                    MarketValueses = (
                        from mv in e.Elements("buy")
                        select new MarketValue
                        {
                            Volume = (int) mv.Element("volume"),
                            Avg = (double) mv.Element("avg"),
                            Max = (double)mv.Element("max"),
                            Min = (double)mv.Element("min"),
                            Stddev = (double)mv.Element("stddev"),
                            Median = (double)mv.Element("median"),
                            Percentile = (double)mv.Element("percentile")
                        }).ToArray()
               }).ToList();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your link only brings back a set of numbers, not any XML. Maybe this QA can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object

Comment: @John, it returns XML; probably your browser just treated it as HTML rather than displaying it raw.

Comment: Ok duly noted. I think the QA mentioned will help to serialize the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you want to fetch the `id` attribute of `type` element but you are trying to fetch it with `type id` which is wrong. Also you have the values of `MarketValue` in three nodes i.e. *buy,sell & all* but currently you are fetching details from just *buy* node.

This should give you the expected output:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("http://api.eve-central.c...
var result = xdoc.Root.Elements("type")
                 .Select(ms => new MarketStat
                    {
                        Name = (string)ms.Attribute("id"),
                        MarketValueses = ms.Elements()
                                      .Select(mv => new MarketValue
                                         {
                                             Volume = (long)mv.Element("volume"),
                                             Avg = (double)mv.Element("avg"),
                                             Max = (double)mv.Element("max"),
                                             Min = (double)mv.Element("min"),
                                             Stddev = (double)mv.Element("stddev"),
                                             Median = (double)mv.Element("median"),
                                             Percentile = (double)mv.Element("percentile")
                                         }).ToArray()
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Code give me an error of empty `result` list. When I'm using `Root.Elements("marketstat").Select(ms => new MarketStat` with `Name = (string) ms.Element("type").Attribute("id")` its working for `type id` node but array which should hold `buy` `sell` `all` give me an error. Please check the code again for me.

Comment: @user5671675 - Yeah that's because now you have `evec_api` as the root node so this line is failing `xdoc.Root.Elements("type")`. In order to traverse through the XML you need to tell `type` node is present inside `marketstat` node, so your code should be :- `xdoc.Root.Element("marketstat").Elements("type")` _Or Else_ you can directly fetch all the _type_ nodes like this:- `xdoc.Descendants("type").Select...`

Comment: Thank you. Now I see where is my problem, with working code I will keep doing exercises and skill up with XML Documents.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an element called "type id". That's not a valid name for an element in XML. You should just look for elements called `type`... that's the name of this element:

```
<type id="34">
```

If you want to filter by ID, you could then fetch the *attribute* `id`.

You're also trying to fetch the `buy` element directly from the `marketstat` element - it isn't there; it's within the `type` element. You need to pay more attention to the structure of the XML, basically.

My guess is that you should only expect a single `buy` element, too - which makes things simpler. I suspect you don't need an array within each element of your results...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things wrong with your xml parsing.

first of all you can't call type id as you do here

```
Name = (string) e.Element("type id")
```

id is an attribute of the type element so you would have to do something like this

```
Name = e.Element("type").Attributes("id").Value
```

Another issue is in the section where you are trying to iterate the buy values.
you have the following line

```
from mv in e.Elements("buy")
```

This will not work because e is the document root element.  buy is a child of the type element so you would want something like this

```
from mv in e.Elements("type").Descendants("buy")
```

Hope this helps and points you in the right direction

Here is a working example

```
list = (
    from e in XDocument.Load("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&usesystem=30000142").
        Root.Elements("marketstat")
        let type = e.Element("type")
    select new MarketStat
    {
        Name = type.Attribute("id").Value,
        MarketValueses = (
            from mv in type.Descendants("buy")
            select new MarketValue
            {
                Volume = long.Parse(mv.Element("volume").Value),
                Avg = double.Parse(mv.Element("avg").Value),
                Max = double.Parse(mv.Element("max").Value),
                Min = double.Parse(mv.Element("min").Value),
                Stddev = double.Parse(mv.Element("stddev").Value),
                Median = double.Parse(mv.Element("median").Value),
                Percentile = double.Parse(mv.Element("percentile").Value)
            }).ToArray()
    }).ToList();
```

** On a side note, when parsing that xml, the volume value was too large to fit into an int32 value so I changed it to a long