# Gridview: Filling it in from a WebService (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, gridview

Okay so my question is two parts:

I retrieve from a webservice about 10 relevant IDs and Names based on the given parameter. Is their a way to convert the response into some list?

The response is like :

```
 ID1:XXX - Name1: test1 - Address1: Narnia - Gender1: M
 ID2:YYY - Name2: test2 - Address2: Hogwarts - Gender2: NA
```

**The second part:**

How do I fill in a gridview from the retrieved list above? And have like certain conditioning like if Address is Hogwarts I'd have an extra column (ex: Desc: ) Where you fill it in your house name or if the house Address is N\A then the Desc column becomes mandatory to be filled in.

Comment: Is that the totality of your response, or is the response formatted in XML oor Json?

Comment: The response is formatted in XML

Comment: Check out https://www.google.com/search?q=c-sharp+deserialize+xml+response+into+class&ie=&oe=

Comment: Doesn't really help . . . I can perfectly read the webservice but I want to input the data into a list. I have the field xResponse that has everything returned. But I'm trying to return it into a list so that I may call it and fill in fields automatically. That's for the 1st part of the question. The second part is the important part. How would I be able to do it?

Comment: You need t deserialize the XML response into a List of objects... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object