# How to create dynamics command object

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I created a few classes that represent Commands to my car:

- `PaintCommand`.
- `RefuelCommand`.

This classes implemented `ICommand` Interface, Contain `Execute(Car c)` method.

Example:

```
    public class RefuelCommand : ICommand
{
    public RefuelCommand()
    {
    }


    public void Execute(Car car)
    {
        car.SetFuel(100);
    }
}
```

I used command patterns to init the commands.

Now, i want to be able to add new `Command` without change the code.

Assume i want now `Change Name command`

Does anyone have an idea?

**My Idea:**

Create a xml file that describe the class command. (Name, Param) and generate from it a new `Command` object.

Comment: Your question is unclear; are you asking about how to deserialise objects from XML?  If so, have a look at these questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object   and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to implement a generic command which could accept a delegate as argument.

That is, it'll be possible to add as many commands as needed during run-time:

```
public interface ICommand
{
     void Execute(Car car);
}

public class GenericCommand : ICommand
{
     public GenericCommand(Action<Car> executePredicate)
     {
           Contract.Requires(executePredicate != null);

           ExecutePredicate = executePredicate;
     }

     private Action<Car> ExecutePredicate { get; }

     public void Execute(Car car) => ExecutePredicate(car);
}
```

Thus, you'll be able to create commands as follows:

```
ICommand command1 = new GenericCommand
(
    car =>
    {
        // Do stuff here with a given car
    }
);

ICommand command2 = new GenericCommand
(
    car =>
    {
        // Do stuff here with a given car
    }
);

ICommand commandN = new GenericCommand
(
    car =>
    {
        // Do stuff here with a given car
    }
);
```

Comment: How can i transfer a delegate at Run time?

Comment: @maz I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the code using T4 templates. For example, create this XML file and place it in your bin folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<command>  
  <name>NameCommand</name>
  <param>Car</param>  
</command>
```

Now add a new item to your project:

1. Right click project node in solution explorer > Add > New Item > Visual C# Items and select Text Template.
2. Give your template a name. I called it ICommandGenerator.

In the template place the following code:

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>  
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml"#>  
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System" #> 
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>  
<#  
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  
// Replace this file path with yours:  
doc.Load(Host.ResolvePath(@"bin\debug\NameCommand.xml"));  
var className = doc.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText;
var paramName = doc.GetElementsByTagName("param")[0].InnerText;
#>
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public partial class <#= className #> 
    {
        public <#= className #>() {}

        public void Execute(<#= paramName #> p)
        {
            // your code here...
        }
    }
}
```

Right click on the TT file in solution explorer and select Run Custom Tool. It will generate the class below using the XML file. This class will be a child node of the TT file so expand the TT file and you will see this class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public partial class NameCommand 
    {
        public NameCommand() {}

        public void Execute(Car p)
        {
            // your code here...
        }
    }
}
```

You can modify the TT file to use another namespace instead of the `ConsoleApplication`. You can even put a bunch of `Command` types in the XML file and loop through all of them and generate many classes. You can read more about T4 templates [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd820614.aspx).

This is how EF generates classes using database first technique wherein you instruct EF by pointing it towards a database using a connection string. EF then analyses your database and eventually places a .tt in your project.