# AspNet Core - Deserialize XML returns null

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deserialize a simple XML, but it Always returns null to my object.

XML

```
<ns0:Customer xmlns:ns0="http://myNameSpace.Customer">
  <Company>001</Company>
  <Division>003</Division>
</ns0:Customer>
```

CLASS

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Customer", Namespace = "http://myNameSpace.Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Division")]
    public string Division { get; set; }
}
```

CODE

```
File.AppendAllText(fileName, string.Format("Polling at {0}\n", DateTime.Now.ToString("o")));
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath
                    + @"\Customers\Customer.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    var customers = ((Customer)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream));
                }
```

RESULT

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: Just to be sure, could you use breakpoints/logging to verify that the file gets populated correctly, and your `fileStream` is correctly created?

Comment: Based on [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10518657/6741868) your steps are more or less correct. That's why I asked you to verify the XML, since if it contains a few `Customer` objects (not just 1), you'd need to try `new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Customer>));` and `var customers = ((List<Customer>)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream));`

Comment: Gonna try all the answers, just a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your containing element does not define a default namespace, so the default namespace of the document is an empty string.

This means that `<Company>` and `<Division>` don't have the same namespace as the containing element, and inherit the default namespace `""`.

Your example will work if you rewrite the attributes to take this into account:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Customer", Namespace = "http://myNameSpace.Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Company", Namespace = "")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Division", Namespace = "")]
    public string Division { get; set; }
}
```

as is demonstrated below:

```
var xmlStr = @" <ns0:Customer xmlns:ns0=""http://myNameSpace.Customer"">
                 <Company>001</Company>
                 <Division>003</Division>
                </ns0:Customer>";
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlStr));
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
var customer = ((Customer)serializer.Deserialize(ms));
//yay. fully populated
```

Comment: You deserve a cookie my good sir!

I doesn't know very much about XML. Thank you for the explanation and solution

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! This is really helpful. I spent whole day to figure it out the issue.