# Find max value from xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml like this, the value of EUR changes every day, How can I find the max Value of the EUR for example for a specific period, for ex. I will have an object with the following("10.07.2017""10.08.2017","EUR"). and from this period  how can I find the max value ? I tried with Linq but no success...

```
     <CurrencyDate="10.08.2017" name="Bank">
<Valute ID="47">
<NumCode>978</NumCode>
<CharCode>EUR</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Euro</Name>
<Value>21.0384</Value>
</Valute>
    </CurrencyDate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply follow below steps:

1. Convert xml to object using serializer. (you can take help from [Convert XML String to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187444/convert-xml-string-to-object) or [How to deserialize xml to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object))
2. Thereafter use LINQ query for getting max value.

Comment: IMO you should try to be more thurough in your answers. Include complete examples instead of [only posting links to other places](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/147063). "use LINQ query" really doesn't say much. It would be fairly simple to show an example of `.Max()` instead.