# c# deserializate xml embedded node to class property

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

i have part of xml document

```
<Tender SubTenderType="BC" TenderType="Check">
   <TenderTotal>
      <Amount>10.00</Amount>
   </TenderTotal>
</Tender>
```

i need convert it to class.

```
public class Tender
{
    public string SubTenderType { get; set; } 
    public string TenderType { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

what i already wrote and this work. but i interseing can i deserialize xml to class as written above?

```
[Serializable]
public class Tender
{
    [XmlAttribute("SubTenderType")]
    public string SubTenderType { get; set; }       

    [XmlAttribute("TenderType")]
    public string TenderType { get; set; }      

    [XmlElement("TenderTotal")]
    public TenderTotal TenderTotal { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class TenderTotal
{
    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize xml to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object)

Comment: There are a lot of existed answers available

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Comment: @OlegI it is not duplicate

Comment: @OlegI maybe i wrong ask. i want remove class TenderTotal. and deserialize xml to class    "class Tender
{
    public string SubTenderType { get; set; } 
    public string TenderType { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}"

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize xml to first Type "Tender" and next use autoMapper to map your type (create new object of different type)

create map:

```
config.CreateMap<TenderFirst, TenderSecond>().ForMember(x => x.TenderTotal.Amount, y => y.Amount ())
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the following class without `XmlAttribute`:

```
public class Tender
{
    public string SubTenderType { get; set; } 
    public string TenderType { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the `XmlAttributeOverrides` class to override the behavior of the serializer in such a way that instead of elements it would do the attributes.

```
var attrSTT = new XmlAttributes { XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("SubTenderType") };
var attrTT = new XmlAttributes { XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("TenderType") };

var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(Tender), nameof(Tender.SubTenderType), attrSTT);
overrides.Add(typeof(Tender), nameof(Tender.TenderType), attrTT);

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tender), overrides);
```

However, in this way impossible add a new item or wrap one element in another.

---

Therefore, you have to do custom serialization, or map one type to another, or writing a custom xml reader/writer, or perform the read/write manually (for example, using linq2xml). There are many ways...