# LINQ to XML parsing single object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse XML document like this:

```
<root>
    <first>1</first>
    <second>2</second>
</root>
```

To structure like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    ...

    public string First;
    public string Second;
}
```

but as far as I understood, I can create new object only in select statement, which only can be applied to collection and root element is not a collection.

Of course, I can select fields separately like:

```
new SomeClass(doc.Element("first").Value, doc.Element("second").Value);
```

But I'm really interested if is it possible to do it in **one** LINQ statement (using `doc` variable only once and creating object inside the LINQ statement)?

In other words: is it possible to create an object not in `Select()` method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object

Comment: What you have there is about as good as it's going to get with that example.

Comment: @GentiSaliu no, I'd like to make it using LINQ. Of course, there are a lot of different ways to parse this object besides LINQ, but i'm trying to learn LINQ here.

Comment: I think it is not possible to do it with out deserialize it.

Answer (score 1):

The root element may not be a collection, but when you parse the xml, your doc variable ***is*** a collection of elements, including root element. So you can still use Select:

```
string xml = @"<root><first>1</first><second>2</second></root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var collectionOfSomeClass = doc.Elements()
                            .Select(x => new SomeClass 
                                        { First = x.Element("first").Value, 
                                          Second = x.Element("second").Value 
                                        });
```