# Unable to deserialize JSON response

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net, json-deserialization

Hi I am Getting an XML response from the API and I am converting that XML response to JSON and then ingesting data in database using C# objects. After converting that XML into JSON and deserializing that JSON is throwing me the error as below.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'AMZ_All_Orders_Datewise.Program+OrderItem' 
because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or 
change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface 
(e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute 
can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'AmazonEnvelope.Message[116].Order.OrderItem', line 1, position 107783.'
```

The code used for converting XML to JSON is below

```
//Response from API is stored in xml variable
string xml = Response.Content;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string Jsontext = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

XML converted JSON response is stored in Jsontext variable. now the JSON is deserialized using Newtonsoft JSON package

```
Root_Orders_Data root_Orders_Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root_Orders_Data>(Jsontext);
```

While executing this above line then above error is thrown.
Please help me with this. Suggest any idea or any corrections.
XML response is Below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
     <DocumentVersion>1.00</DocumentVersion>
     </Header>
    <MessageType>AllOrdersReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
         <Order>
            <AmazonOrderID>407-4867592-2717133</AmazonOrderID>
            <MerchantOrderID>407-4867592-2717133</MerchantOrderID>
            <PurchaseDate>2021-01-03T18:29:44+00:00</PurchaseDate>
            <LastUpdatedDate>2021-01-05T08:03:11+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>
            <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
            <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
            <FulfillmentData>
               <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
               <ShipServiceLevel>Expedited</ShipServiceLevel>
               <Address>
                  <City>PATNA</City>
                  <State>BIHAR</State>
                  <PostalCode>800020</PostalCode>
                  <Country>IN</Country>
               </Address>
           </FulfillmentData>
           <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>
           <IsSoldByAB>false</IsSoldByAB>
           <OrderItem>
              <AmazonOrderItemCode>65393459928915</AmazonOrderItemCode>
              <ASIN>B07GMRJTS9</ASIN>
              <SKU>CT4G4DFS8266-01</SKU>
              <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>
              <ProductName>Crucial RAM 4GB DDR4 2666 MHz CL19 Desktop Memory CT4G4DFS8266</ProductName>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              <ItemPrice>
                 <Component>
                    <Type>Principal</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">1450.0</Amount>
                 </Component>
                 <Component>
                    <Type>Shipping</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">40.0</Amount>
                 </Component>
              </ItemPrice>
              <Promotion>
                <PromotionIDs>IN Core Free Shipping 2015/04/08 23-48-5-108</PromotionIDs>
                 <ShipPromotionDiscount>40.0</ShipPromotionDiscount>
              </Promotion>
           </OrderItem>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
         <Order>
            <AmazonOrderID>406-0676704-1460352</AmazonOrderID>
            <MerchantOrderID>406-0676704-1460352</MerchantOrderID>
            <PurchaseDate>2021-01-01T17:58:26+00:00</PurchaseDate>
            <LastUpdatedDate>2021-01-02T07:27:17+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>
            <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
            <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
            <FulfillmentData>
               <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
               <ShipServiceLevel>Expedited</ShipServiceLevel>
               <Address>
                  <City>BENGALURU</City>
                  <State>KARNATAKA</State>
                  <PostalCode>560051</PostalCode>
                  <Country>IN</Country>
               </Address>
           </FulfillmentData>
           <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>
           <IsSoldByAB>false</IsSoldByAB>
           <OrderItem>
              <AmazonOrderItemCode>65883701062139</AmazonOrderItemCode>
              <ASIN>B07Z87LXY1</ASIN>
              <SKU>F4-3600C16D-16GTZRC</SKU>
              <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>
              <ProductName>G.Skill F4-3600C16D-16GTZRC Trident Z RGB DDR4-3600MHz CL16-19-19-39 1.35V 16GB (2x8GB) Memory</ProductName>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              <ItemPrice>
                 <Component>
                    <Type>Principal</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">11699.0</Amount>
                 </Component>
              </ItemPrice>
           </OrderItem>
           <OrderItem>
              <AmazonOrderItemCode>29991566012307</AmazonOrderItemCode>
              <ASIN>B089XVWVZ9</ASIN>
              <SKU>90MB1490-M0IAY0</SKU>
              <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>
              <ProductName>ASUS TUF Gaming B550M-Plus AM4 PCIe 4.0 DDR4 (4600 O.C.) mATX Motherboard with 2.5Gb Ethernet WiFi 6 2X M.2 USB 3.2 Gen2 and Aura Sync RGB Support</ProductName>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              <ItemPrice>
                 <Component>
                    <Type>Principal</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">15940.0</Amount>
                 </Component>
              </ItemPrice>
           </OrderItem>
        </Order>
    </Message>
    <Message>
         <Order>
            <AmazonOrderID>171-4651818-8974757</AmazonOrderID>
            <MerchantOrderID>171-4651818-8974757</MerchantOrderID>
            <PurchaseDate>2021-01-01T17:54:10+00:00</PurchaseDate>
            <LastUpdatedDate>2021-01-02T07:26:52+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>
            <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
            <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
            <FulfillmentData>
               <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
               <ShipServiceLevel>Expedited</ShipServiceLevel>
               <Address>
                  <City>Anantapur</City>
                  <State>ANDHRA PRADESH</State>
                  <PostalCode>515001</PostalCode>
                  <Country>IN</Country>
               </Address>
           </FulfillmentData>
           <IsBusinessOrder>false</IsBusinessOrder>
           <IsSoldByAB>false</IsSoldByAB>
           <OrderItem>
              <AmazonOrderItemCode>38919417111003</AmazonOrderItemCode>
              <ASIN>B07HY3QWM7</ASIN>
              <SKU>DTSWIVL/16GBIN</SKU>
              <ItemStatus>Shipped</ItemStatus>
              <ProductName>Kingston DataTraveler Swivl 16GB USB 3.0 Pen Drive (DTSWIVL/16GBIN)</ProductName>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              <ItemPrice>
                 <Component>
                    <Type>Principal</Type>
                    <Amount currency="INR">399.0</Amount>
                 </Component>
              </ItemPrice>
           </OrderItem>
        </Order>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

C# objects are below

```
public class Header
        {
            public string DocumentVersion { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
        }

        public class FulfillmentData
        {
            public string FulfillmentChannel { get; set; }
            public string ShipServiceLevel { get; set; }
            public Address Address { get; set; }
        }

        public class Amount
        {
            public string _currency { get; set; }
            public string __text { get; set; }
        }

        public class Component
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public Amount Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class ItemPrice
        {
            public List<Component> Component { get; set; }
        }

        public class Promotion
        {
            public string PromotionIDs { get; set; }
            public string ShipPromotionDiscount { get; set; }
        }

        public class OrderItem
        {
            public string AmazonOrderItemCode { get; set; }
            public string ASIN { get; set; }
            public string SKU { get; set; }
            public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public string Quantity { get; set; }
            public ItemPrice ItemPrice { get; set; }
            public Promotion Promotion { get; set; }
            public string NumberOfItems { get; set; }
        }

        public class Order
        {
            public string AmazonOrderID { get; set; }
            public string MerchantOrderID { get; set; }
            public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
            public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
            public string SalesChannel { get; set; }
            public FulfillmentData FulfillmentData { get; set; }
            public string IsBusinessOrder { get; set; }
            public string IsSoldByAB { get; set; }
            public List<OrderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }
            public string FulfilledBy { get; set; }
        }

        public class Message
        {
            public Order Order { get; set; }
        }

        public class AmazonEnvelope
        {
            public Header Header { get; set; }
            public string MessageType { get; set; }
            public List<Message> Message { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("_xmlns:xsi")]
            public string XmlnsXsi { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("_xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation")]
            public string XsiNoNamespaceSchemaLocation { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root_Orders_Data
        {
            public AmazonEnvelope AmazonEnvelope { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: The issue is in `Root_Orders_Data` and the Json. There is a mismatch with `AMZ_All_Orders_Datewise.Program+OrderItem` type. More exactly The deserilizer found a Json Array [1,2,3] instead of an object. 
For your question I fail to see why you provided the XML. And the Xml deserialization.

Comment: One weird question why not deserilize Xml to object directly? Instead of doing the json step? https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/. If you didn't find the Special past XMl to class in visual studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize xml to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object)

Comment: I was unable to serialize XML to C sharp its throwing some errors.

Comment: What is the final objective? If it is to save data in a database, there is no need in JSON, no need in c# objects. Just pass XML as-is to a database, shred it there, and save in a database. What is your database?

Comment: Hi @YitzhakKhabinsky, Thanks for your help here. I am using MS SQL server as Database. How can I directly ingest data into a Table in Database can u please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example for you.

It covers one-to-many scenario similar to yours for Order and OrderDetails.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE #orders (
   OurOrderID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderID      CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
    CustomerID   CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
    OrderDate   DATE       NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID   INT        NOT NULL
);
    
CREATE TABLE #details (
   OrderDetailID INT IDENTITY,
   OurOrderID   INT           NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #orders(OurOrderID),
    ProductID   INT           NOT NULL,
    Price      DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    Qty         INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderDetailID, OurOrderID, ProductID)
);
    
DECLARE @orderidmap TABLE (
   OurOrderID   INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TheirOrderID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
                          
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Orders>
    <Order OrderID="13000" CustomerID="ALFKI" OrderDate="2006-09-20Z" EmployeeID="2">
        <OrderDetails ProductID="76" Price="123" Qty="10"/>
        <OrderDetails ProductID="16" Price="3.23" Qty="20"/>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="13001" CustomerID="VINET" OrderDate="2006-09-20Z" EmployeeID="1">
        <OrderDetails ProductID="12" Price="12.23" Qty="1"/>
    </Order>
</Orders>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

/*
Propagate generated IDENTITY values for PRIMARY KEY as FOREIGN KEY in the child table
=============================================================================================
We have an XML document with order data, and there is an order ID in that data. 
To be able to store both header and details, we need a mapping, 
and to this end we use the MERGE statement with the odd condition 1 = 0 
in the USING clause and there is only one branch for WHEN NOT MATCHED. 
We use the OUTPUT clause, and we insert both order IDs into the @orderidmap table.    
*/
;WITH OrderData AS 
(
    SELECT TheirOrderID = c.value('@OrderID[1]',    'INT'),
           CustomerID   = c.value('@CustomerID[1]', 'CHAR(5)'),
           OrderDate    = c.value('@OrderDate[1]',  'DATETIME'),
           EmployeeID   = c.value('@EmployeeID[1]', 'SMALLINT')
    FROM   @xml.nodes('/Orders/Order') AS t(c)
 )
 MERGE #orders AS o
 USING OrderData AS od ON 1 = 0
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, EmployeeID)  
       VALUES(od.TheirOrderID, od.CustomerID, od.OrderDate, od.EmployeeID)
 OUTPUT inserted.OurOrderID, od.TheirOrderID 
   INTO @orderidmap (OurOrderID, TheirOrderID);
    
;WITH Details AS 
(
    SELECT TheirOrderID = o.value('@OrderID[1]',    'INT'),
           ProductID    = od.value('@ProductID[1]',   'SMALLINT'),
           Price        = od.value('@Price[1]',     'DECIMAL(10,2)'),
           Qty          = od.value('@Qty[1]',       'INT')
    FROM   @xml.nodes('/Orders/Order') AS A(o)
      CROSS APPLY A.o.nodes('OrderDetails') AS B(od)
) 
INSERT #details (OurOrderID, ProductID, Price, Qty)
SELECT m.OurOrderID, d.ProductID, d.Price, d.Qty
FROM   Details AS d
   INNER JOIN @orderidmap AS m ON d.TheirOrderID = m.TheirOrderID;

-- test    
SELECT * FROM #orders;
SELECT * FROM @orderidmap;
SELECT * FROM #details;
GO
DROP TABLE #orders, #details;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But my requirement is to ingest the XML response from API into the database on regular basis. like each and every time ill call the API get the XML response and ingest it into the Database. can u help me with anything like that.

Comment: @Abdul, Just package what I showed you as a stored procedure. And call it from the application by passing XML parameter to it as many times as needed.