# C# XML reader doesn't get the value from child nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file with child nodes that I want to read.
When I deserialize the object I won't get the value from the child nodes, its always 0.

Xmlfile example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pieces Rapport="0" Employee="">
  <Piece Roll="1" Piece="1" Amount="1" Length="1.00" />
  <Piece Roll="1" Piece="1" Amount="1" Length="2.00" />
  <Piece Roll="1" Piece="1" Amount="1" Length="3.00" />
  <Piece Roll="1" Piece="1" Amount="1" Length="0" />
  <Piece Roll="1" Piece="1" Amount="1" Length="0" />
</Pieces>
```

I marked my classes with the `[XmlElement]` tag as stated here: [How to deserialize xml to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518372/how-to-deserialize-xml-to-object)

classes:

```
  [XmlRoot("Pieces")]
public class StukLijst
{
    [XmlElement("Rapport")]
    public string rapport { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Employee")]
    public string employee { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Piece")]
    public List<StukRow> stukLijst { get; set; }
}

 public class StukRow
{
    [XmlElement("Roll")]
    public int rol { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Piece")]
    public int stuk { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public int banen { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Length")]
    public double lengte { get; set; }
}
```

read the xml file:

```
private void LoadXml(string pickListNumber, string lineNumber)
    {
        string path = filePath + pickListNumber + "_" + lineNumber + ".xml";
        StreamReader xmlStream = new StreamReader(path);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StukLijst));
        StukLijst result = (StukLijst)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
    }
```

and the result is the following:

[image: result]

So why is Employee `null` while the childnodes are all `0`?
It seems like it can find the childs but doesn't get the data from them.
Any solutions?

Comment: Arent you mixing elements and attributes? A new XML node is an element,  but `Rapport` and `Employee` are not new XML nodes, but attributes of the existing `Pieces` node/element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used `[XmlElement]` in each of your properties in `StukRow`, but the data isn't in XML elements - it's in XML *attributes*. Try this instead:

```cs
public class StukRow
{
    [XmlAttribute("Roll")]
    public int rol { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Piece")]
    public int stuk { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Amount")]
    public int banen { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Length")]
    public double lengte { get; set; }
}
```

Likewise your `rapport` and `employee` properties in `StukLijst` should be decorated with `[XmlAttribute]` as the data is in stored in XML attributes, not child elements.

As a side-note, I'd strongly encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions for your properties, using PascalCased names (e.g. `Rol`, `Stuk` etc.)

Comment: Correct. I should have used XmlAttribute.